# Can you earn money other than $50,000?

Tags: poker-night-at-the-inventory

If I were to quit a game halfway though would I earn the money I have or would I just loose $10,000?

In other words, can I cut my losses and run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As each of the 5 players starts with $10,000 and stays in the game until they are broke, there are two possible outcomes:

- You lose, going broke, losing $10,000
- You win, getting all the money, earning $40,000 ($50,000 total - $10,000 starting capital.)

Quitting prematurely will count as a loss, and will cause you to lose your $10,000

If you get one of the special items as a bet from one the characters, these will take place of the $10,000 of that character, and the amount of money is adjusted accordingly. ($40,000 total + 1 item, instead of $50,000 total)